# Node.js Sequelize combine count in filter

Tags: sql, node.js, filter, sequelize.js

I am working on a Node.JS project with Sequelize.

I have a service that receives multiple filters from the frontend and it combines these filters in order to answer.

I have Document, Email_Logs entities with M-N connection.

I have a specific filter for showing records that a relevant email has been sent or not.

I define:

1. Sent: is_mail_sent=1
2. Not Sent: is_mail_sent=null
3. Both: is_mail_sent:-1

The first case is working.
In the second case i want:

> COUNT(Doc_Email_Logs)=0 OR (COUNT(Doc_Email_Logs)>0 AND
> Doc_Email_Logs.status=0)

but I can't figure out how to include the count in the filter.

Code:

```
const { doc_types, order_id, loading_id, from_date, to_date, is_mail_sent, supplier_id, client_id, transporter_id, order_category_id } = req.query;
  let filter = {};

  if (order_id !== 'null') {
    filter['$order_load_docs.order_id$'] = {
      [Op.like]: `%${order_id}%`,
    };
  }

  if (loading_id !== 'null') {
    filter['$order_load_docs.loading_id$'] = {
      [Op.like]: `%${loading_id}%`,
    };
  }

  if (supplier_id !== 'null') {
    filter['$order_load_docs.supplier_id$'] = {
      [Op.eq]: `${supplier_id}`,
    };
  }
  if (client_id !== 'null') {
    filter['$order_load_docs.client_id$'] = {
      [Op.eq]: `${client_id}`,
    };
  }
  if (order_category_id !== 'null') {
    filter['$order_load_docs.order_category_id$'] = {
      [Op.eq]: `${order_category_id}`,
    };
  }

  
  const normalizeDocTypes = Array.isArray(doc_types)
    ? doc_types
    : doc_types
      ? [doc_types]
      : [];
      
    if (normalizeDocTypes.length > 0) {
        filter["$type.id$"] = {
            [Op.in]: normalizeDocTypes,
        };
    }


  if (from_date!=='null' && to_date!=='null') {
    filter.createdAt = {
      [Op.between]: [new Date(from_date), new Date(to_date)],
    };
  }



  console.log(is_mail_sent)
  if(is_mail_sent==1){  //Sent
    filter['$Doc_Email_Logs.status$'] = {
      [Op.eq]: is_mail_sent,
    };
  }

  if(is_mail_sent=='null'){  //Not Sent
    console.log('edw')
    filter['$Doc_Email_Logs.status$'] = {
      [Op.eq]: 0
    };
  }

  if(is_mail_sent==-1){  //Both

  }



  // if (is_mail_sent!==null || is_mail_sent!==-1) {
  //   if(is_mail_sent==1){
  //     filter['$Doc_Email_Logs.status$'] = {
  //       [Op.eq]: is_mail_sent,
  //     };
  //   }else{
  //     filter['$Doc_Email_Logs.status$'] = {
  //       [Op.or]: [
  //         { [Op.eq]: null }, // Count = 0
  //         {
  //           [Op.and]: [
  //             { [Op.ne]: null }, // Count > 0
  //             { [Op.not]: { [Op.col]: 'Doc_Email_Logs.status' } } // Status <> 1
  //           ]
  //         }
  //       ]
  //     };
  //   }
  // }
  // if(is_mail_sent==-1){ //Both Sent and not sent
  //   filter['$Doc_Email_Logs.status$'] = {
  //     [Op.or]: [
  //       { [Op.eq]: 1 }, // Case 1: is_mail_sent equals 1
  //       {
  //         [Op.or]: [
  //           { [Op.eq]: null }, // Count = 0
  //           {
  //             [Op.and]: [
  //               { [Op.ne]: null }, // Count > 0
  //               { [Op.not]: { [Op.col]: 'Doc_Email_Logs.status' } }, // Status <> 1
  //             ],
  //           },
  //         ],
  //       },
  //     ],
  //   };
  // }

  
  return Document.findAll({
    where: filter,
    include: [
      {
        model: db.document_type,
        as: 'type',
        attributes: ['type_name', 'type_color']
      },
      {
        model: db.order_loading_document_j,
        as: 'order_load_docs',
        attributes: ['loading_id', 'order_id', 'supplier_id','client_id' , 'order_category_id',  'added_by']
      },
      {
        model: db.email_log,
        as: 'Doc_Email_Logs',
        attributes: ['status', 'status_text', 'createdAt']
      }
    ],
    order: db.sequelize.literal('createdAt DESC'),
    attributes: ['id', 'local_path', 'filesize', 'web_path', 'createdAt']
  })
```

Both